# React Access Variable from All Components

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, so excuse me if this is a dumb question. Is there a way to make a variable public and accessible from all other components within react? For instance I am setting a boolean value in one component and I would like to be able to access that boolean from any of the other components. Is this possible? Or am I stuck within the confines of parent/child relationships?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try redux - https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to manage state across components or you can use state management libraries like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

If you want to have share only one `Boolean` as you specified in your question, Better go with Context as it is builtin with `React`

Basic Usage of Context will be as follows

Please find the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-dew-0s6lj) for basic implementation of context

Answer (score 0):

Use `Context` for state sharing or use `Redux` or `Mobx` for global state management.

Comment: You can also use `localStorage` for data sharing for small application.